# Central Limit Theorem approximation question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

> Suppose that the error, in grams, of a balance has the density
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}e^\frac{-|x|}{2}$$ for $-∞<x<∞$, and that 100 items
>   are weighed, independently of each other. Use the Central Limit
>   Theorem to approximate the probability that the absolute difference
>   between the true total weight and the measured total weight is more
>   than 50 grams.

I have calculated that $EX=0$ and $varX=8$ which I know is correct. As I understand it, I want to approximate $$P(X>50)=1-P(X\leqslant 0)$$But I am not sure I understand how this can be done using the theorem... Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on a single weigth has a [Laplace distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) with mean $0$ and variance $8$.

By the CLT, when $100$ items are weigthed, the distribution of the cumulative error is very close to a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $0$ and variance $800$, so a really close approximation of the probability that the cumulative error exceeds $50$ in absolute value is given by:

$$1-\frac{1}{40\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-50}^{50}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{1600}\right)\,dx =1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-5/4}^{5/4}e^{-x^2}\,dx\approx \color{red}{7,71\%}.$$